# Creating a view with nested queries

Tags: sql

```
 Use Surveydb;  
 create view VW_Service
    As 
    (select A.id as 'Encounter ID'
           ,A.startDateTime as 'Enconter StartDateTime'
           ,A.endDateTime as 'Encounter EndDateTime'
           ,B.id as 'Service ID'
           ,B.startDateTime as 'Service StartDateTime'
           ,B.endDateTime as 'Service EndDateTime'
           ,C.label as 'Services Name Code Label'
           ,C.symbol as 'Service Name Code Symbol'
           ,C.system as 'Service Name Code System'
     from Code C,
          Encounter A,
          Service B
     where 
     a.id = b.encounterId
     and c.id = b.nameCodeId) 
     JOIN
     (select a.label as 'Service Status Code Label'
           ,a.symbol as 'Service Status Code Symbol'
           ,b.system as 'Services Status Code System'
      from
      Code a, Code b
      Where
      a.id = b.id )
```

I'm trying to create a view which includes three tables and also need to self join one of the tables. The script above is the separate queries for the view. The first query consist of all the three table and the second subquery is the self join query from code table. I'm trying to join both queries. Any thoughts?

Comment: Hi, couple questions to begin with. Which Database engine you use and secondly what is the error you get from the above SQL? Thanks!

Comment: I think you are asking for the optmizatrion for the above query. So please post some sample data and your expected O/P result.

Comment: What fields are common between these two subqueries? How are they joined? Once you specify that we can write out the rest of the missing pieces.

Comment: @TedFilippidis This query is missing a SELECT clause, an ON clause and proper aliases for the subqueries/derived tables. The errors are numerous and the bigs ones are obvious.

Comment: what database are u using?

Answer (score 0):

Join of 2 subqueries is pretty straightforward: You just get 2 subqueries and join them as usual tables. Like this:

```
select *
from (select id from table a) as a
join (select id from table b) as b
  on a.id = b.id
```

You just need to know how to join those subqueries. In your case, I believe it is something from table Code, like id field.

But you "self join" is wired, you don't need it at all, this will give you same result:

```
join (select a.label as 'Service Status Code Label'
       ,a.symbol as 'Service Status Code Symbol'
       ,a.system as 'Services Status Code System'
  from Code a
  )
```